# Custom redirect user after login based on metadata

Tags: redirect, login, user-meta

I have a problem and would like some help:

Scenario:

Table: wp_usermeta

[image]

According to the table above (wp-usermeta), which function could I use for all users with Special Plan after login being redirected to the website.com/special page, Super plan users being redirected to the website.com/super page and users of the Vip plan being redirected to the website.com/vip page?

Comment: Have you looked into `login_redirect`? https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick. Add this filter to your plugins functions file/class. This will run automatically every time anyone logs in, if they are a user who has the 'Vip' plan, they will be redirected to the `/vip/` page. otherwise they will be redirected to the default.

```
add_filter( 'login_redirect', function( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {

    if( ! is_wp_error( $user ) && 'Vip' == get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'plan', true ) ) {
        return home_url( 'vip' );
    } else {
        return $redirect_to;
    }

}, 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Very good, with the tip above I made the redirection to the other plans and it worked perfectly.

```
add_filter( 'login_redirect', function( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {

if( ! is_wp_error( $user ) && 'Vip' == get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'plan', true ) ) {
    return home_url( 'vip' );
} else if( ! is_wp_error( $user ) && 'Special' == get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'plan', true ) ) {
    return home_url( 'special' );
} else if( ! is_wp_error( $user ) && 'Super' == get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'plan', true ) ) {
    return home_url( 'super' );
} else {
    return $redirect_to;
}

}, 10, 3 );
```

Thanks Howdy_McGee and smartcat